# Call javascript function only once on either click event or scroll event for particular class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Let's say i have a javascript function call `function playGauge()`.

I want to call this function only once when either a `div` with `class="myClass"` is clicked or scrolled. For click I am using following code:

```
    var myclassClicked = false;
    $('.myClass').click(playGauge);


    function playGauge(){
    if (myclassClicked === true) return false;
    myclassClicked = true;
///do some other stuff
}
```

How to add **scroll** functionality in a similar way to my code and my `function playGauge()`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

[`$.one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) is your friend:

```
$('.myClass').one('click scroll', function(event){ ... });
```

Comment: That was my first thought as well, but it should be noted that this fires once for *each* element in the collection, and not just one time for all.

Comment: I haven't tested by I am under the impression that it will play once for every `.myClass` elements rather than once for all.

Comment: I'm not sure how it deals with multiple elements, but it fires once for each event type. so you get one for click and one for scroll: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tx84F/)

Comment: @JohnS - you do, but as it's a class selector, there could be more than one element, and then the event handler would fire once for each element -> http://jsfiddle.net/Tx84F/1/

Comment: @adeneo - I originally thought the OP wanted the event handler to run once per matching element, but perhaps I misinterpreted that.

Comment: @JohnS - That could be the case, it's a little unclear, so I have really have no idea, was just pointing it out ?

Answer (score 3):

Remove the event handler once the event occurs on any of the elements matching the selector

```
$('.myClass').on('click scroll', function() {
    $('.myClass').off('click scroll')
    playGauge();
});
```

Comment: Using event delegation would be slightly better.

Comment: @plalx - Why on earth would event delegation be better with non-dynamic elements? I don't get that comment at all!

Comment: Well, it all depends on how many `.myClass` elements there is on the page, but it will be more memory-efficient to register a single handler rather than multiple ones if there are many. Perhaps I should have said "using event delegation **could** be slightly better if there are many `.myClass` elements on the page."

Comment: @adeneo a comma was missing in the first line, but it only works for click and not for scroll.

Comment: That's strange, it works fine for me (added the comma btw!) -> http://jsfiddle.net/p8D5Y/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try to add event *scroll* :

```
$('.myClass').scroll(playGauge);
```

[Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/)